# How much virtual memory does a 30.5Gb heap(256 Gb memory in total) for Elasticsearch support?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, virtual-memory

Assume I have a machine with 256gb memory and 12TB SSD. Indexed document size is 100TB. I assign 30.5 GB to Elasticsearch heap. The remaining is for Lucene and OS.

My question is, how much virtual memory does Elasticsearch support? To put it in another way, how many indexed documents can I put into the virtual memory for each machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The amount of [virtual memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#vm-max-map-count) ES can use is defined by the value of the `vm.max_map_count` setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. By default it is set at 262144, but you can change this value using:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

From the [linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> This file contains the maximum number of memory map areas a process
>   may have. Memory map areas are used as a side-effect of calling
>   malloc, directly by mmap and mprotect, and also when loading shared
>   libraries.
>
> While most applications need less than a thousand maps, certain
>   programs, particularly malloc debuggers, may consume lots of them,
>   e.g., up to one or two maps per allocation.
>
> The default value is 65536.

So this setting doesn't impose a specific **size** available to ES/Lucene, but a **number of discrete memory areas** that a given process can use. How much memory is used exactly will depend on the size of the memory chunks being allocated by ES/Lucene. [By default](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/5.2.1/org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory.java?av=f#88), Lucene uses

- `1<<30` = 1,073,741,824 ~= 1GB chunks on a 64 bit JRE and
- `1<<28` = 268,435,456 ~= 256MB chunks on 32 bit JRE

So if you do the math, the default value of `vm.max_map_count` is probably good enough for your case, if not you can tune it and monitor your virtual memory usage.

Comment: When you say memory chunk, do you mean physical memory or virtual memory?